Delta lake table metadata doesn't match file structure
I have a delta table stored in Azure blob storage with data going back to 2022 or so, which includes client_name as a partition. Some time in early 2024 the client_name for some rows was changed to correct for an old typo when the data was first loaded. Unfortunately, this was done by directly renaming the path in blob storage so the delta table metadata is unaware of this change.
Querying for data in the delta table before that point (if not explicitly ignoring the problematic client_name rows) fails because expected files are "missing".
How can I repair the delta table metadata so that it functions correctly?

It depends on how you were writing old and new files. If it was "append-only" mode then you can delete _delta_log folder and recreate Delta table using CONVERT TO DELTA command  https://docs.delta.io/latest/delta-utility.html#convert-a-parquet-table-to-a-delta-table

If you were using UPDATE/DELETE/MERGE then I do not think there is any reliable automatic way to fix.

it was unfortunately done entirely outside of the delta table framework. a file was directly renamed in the blob storage, so the table metadata thinks a file is there that does not exist. Keeping the history would be nice, but having the table actually working is more important. CONVERT TO DELTA seems the likely way to go
